# Mapper decorators in Nest not found by compiler

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am not able to find a way to use of decorators ElasticProperty and ElasticType mentioned [in the documentation](https://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/indices/put-mapping.html). They are nowhere to be found in the Library and it crash at compile time.

Demo code:

```
[ElasticType(
    Name = "elasticsearchprojects2",
    DateDetection = true,
    NumericDetection = true,
    SearchAnalyzer = "standard",
    IndexAnalyzer = "standard",
    DynamicDateFormats = new[] { "dateOptionalTime", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z||yyyy/MM/dd Z" }
)]
public class ElasticSearchProject
{
    public int Id { get; set;  }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ElasticProperty(OmitNorms = true, Index = FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed)]
    public string Country { get; set; }
```

Comment: What version of NEST and Elasticsearch are you using? If you;re using NEST 2.x, take a look at https://www.elastic.co/blog/ga-release-of-nest-2-0-our-dot-net-client-for-elasticsearch and in particular, the links to breaking changes between NEST 1.x and 2.x

Comment: @RussCam It's ES 2.2.0 and Nest 2.0.2 and thanks for the link, will review it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current documentation of Nest is out of date but the team is currently working hard to update it. For now we have [this article about Nest 2.0 breaking changes](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/docs/2.0-breaking-changes/nest-breaking-changes.md) that explains the changes in the API:

> Renamed Types
>
> - class AggregationDescriptor`1
> - class AggregationContainerDescriptor`1
> - class AliasRequest
> - class BulkAliasRequest
> - class AllFieldMapping
> - class AllField
> - class AllocateClusteRerouteCommand
> - class AllocateClusterRerouteCommand
> - class AnalysisSettings
> - class Analysis
> - class AndFilter
> - class AndQuery
> - class AverageAggregator
> - class AverageAggregation

... Body limit reached when pasting all the changes

Answer (score 2):

Based on what I have just reviewed, it seems that NEST API has changed these attributes/decorators by **ElasticSearchType** and **ElasticsearchPropertyAttributeBase** respectively. 
Please verify it

Comment: This is what I found to be true after seeing may confusing references to the old ElasticProperty usage